# Is it possible to get the stack of subflows in spring webFlow

Tags: navigation, spring-webflow

In our application we are using Spring WebFlow to navigate users through the site. In certain pages i need to know from which flow i started the current subflow. Is there any simple way to get this information in Spring WebFlow?

I am using Spring WebFlow version 2.0.9 and unfortunatelly cannot upgrade to newer version.

Simple example:

I am having pages `foo/foo.xhtml` called from `foo/flow.xml`, `bar/bar.xhtml` called from `bar/flow.xml`.
Finally i have `baz/baz.xhtml` that has a `baz/flow.xml`. This is called as subflow from either foo flow or bar flow. In backing bean of baz flow i need to see the "history" how i called my `baz/flow.xml`

Solution found for this question:
*you could also implement your own FLowExecutionListener, and when you enter a StateDefinition you can check if it's an instance of SubflowState and get the name of the parent. Then maybe you could just put that variable in the FlowScope to use it in your state – rptmat57*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a input on the original flow that you would set in each subflow?
in `baz/flow.xml`:

`<input name="comingFrom" type="string">`

in `foo/flow.xml`:

`<subflow-state id="subFlowFoo" subflow="baz">`
`<input name="comingFrom" value="Foo" type="string"/>`
`...`
`</sublfow-state>`

in `bar/flow.xml`:

`<subflow-state id="subFlowBar" subflow="baz">`
`<input name="comingFrom" value="Bar" type="string"/>`
`...`
`</sublfow-state>`

Comment: Yes, that is, how I did it meanwhile, but this solution is not as neat as I would like. In case I will have another flow or deeper structure, it will be an overhead to fill the input variable everywhere.

Comment: true, you could concatenate strings to get the entire stack but it's still not the best.

Comment: you could also implement your own FLowExecutionListener, and when you enter a StateDefinition you can check if it's an instance of SubflowState and get the name of the parent. Then maybe you could just put that variable in the FlowScope to use it in your state

Comment: well, this is a good idea. This may be a solution, that does not need to alter the flow confoguration XMLs and yet may work fine! Thanks for the tip. I will check this answer solved, because your point is worth it! Thanks again